# Best way to write a RESTful service "client" in .Net?

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

What techniques do people use to "consume" services in the REST stile on .Net ? Plain http client? Related to this: many rest services are now using JSON (its tighter and faster) - so what JSON lib is used?

Comment: I bookmarked this blog post ages ago, although I've never tried it. Sounds like it might help you: <http://blogs.msdn.com/nathana/archive/2007/09/13/wcf-web-programming-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-uri-templates.aspx>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach was

1. Write some libraries and interfaces to serialize your objects into REST-compatible XML.
   You can't neccessarily just use the built-in serializers, because your service may not accept the same kind of XML that .NET wants to give you.

   Example: When passing booleans to a Rails REST service, `"true"` gets unserialized as `true`, whereas `"True"` (which .NET gives you) unserializes to `false`.
2. Write some libraries to do the HTTP, wrapping around the basic .NET `WebRequest` objects.
   You might get some mileage out of some third party libraries in this area as it tends to be more standard. I found some issues though, such as this [lovely bug in the .NET framework](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/dana/archive/2006/07/28/1484.aspx), so I'm glad I stuck with the basics.

Comment: I don't know of any .NET serializer that will produce "True". Which one are you referring to? There are no such problems with the XML Serializer.